# Pycharm, debugger не останавливается на точке break point

Tags: pycharm, отладка, отладчик

как написано в описании, ставлю break point, если в последующем коде нет ошибок то Pycharm останавливается на строке которую отметил, выдает все переменные и т.д. все ок. если в последующем коде есть ошибки (пропущеная запятая, неправильно использованая функция и т.д.) то Pycharm игнорирует break point и выдет ошибку выполнения скрипта.
Вопрос, возможен ли запуск Debugger с игнорированием последующих ошибок в коде

Comment: Спасибо, что рассказали сообществу об этом, но сообщество в курсе:-)  Пожалуйста, формулируйте вопросы в дальнейшем - что вы хотите в ответ на свое сообщение? (Если же  у вас тут вопрос "почему", то, полагаю, потому, что компилятор Python байт-код не может создать. Исправьте ошибки).

Comment: Спасибо за исправление вопроса. Вряд ли это возможно - см. мой комментарий выше. Почитайте, как идте создание выполняемого кода. Да и смысла в этом большого нет. Закомментируйте остальную часть кода и запускайте начальную часть, если уж не хотите ошибки исправлять сразу (а имело бы смысл).